# Fragment shader ignores texture coordinates

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I am learning OpenGL through the tutorials at [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/).

I've already drawn my hand-defined 3x3 texture onto a square using 2 triangles without a shader. Using shaders, however, I don't understand this weird behavior:

**The fragment shader seems to ignore texture coordinates** but strangely paints my two triangles with the color of the first pixel. I tried putting garbage values into the texture coordinates and it always stays the same.

```
unsigned char texture_buffer[9*4] = // 3x3 texture RGBA ...
{   
    255,40,100,255,  100,200,200,255,  150,150,200,255,
    100,100,150,255, 200,200,100,255,  150,200,150,255,
    150,100,100,255, 200,100,200,255,  200,150,150,255
};
float positions_texcoords[] =
{   //    x              y            z               tex coords
        0.0f,           0.0f,       0.0f,           0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,           0.0f,       0.0f,           1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,           0.5f,       0.0f,           0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,         0.5f,       0.0f,           1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,         0.0f,       0.0f,           1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,         0.5f,       0.0f,           0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

one time draw call:

```
    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 3, 3, 0,
                 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void *)texture_buffer );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(positions_texcoords), 
                   positions_texcoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // texture coord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glUseProgram(shader_program_id);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);


    SwapBuffers(window_dc);
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 in_tex_coord;

out vec2 out_tex_coord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(in_pos, 1.0);
    out_tex_coord = in_tex_coord;
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core      
out vec4 FragColor;  

in vec2 in_tex_coord;
uniform sampler2D in_texture;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(in_texture, in_tex_coord);
}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions about what might be going on. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of a shader stage is linked to the input of the next shader stage by its name (except when you use a layout qualifier). See [interface matching rules between shader stages.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Interface_matching)

The name of the fragment shader input variable has to be the same as the name of the vertex shader output variable.

Since the name of the texture coordinate output in the vertex shader is `out_tex_coord`

> ```c
> out vec2 out_tex_coord;
> ```

the name of the corresponding input in the fragment shader has to be `out_tex_coord`, too:

```c
in vec2 out_tex_coord;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(in_texture, out_tex_coord);
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I had no idea that the names were linked and defined them as ins and outs :D